# Is DBflow Possible by Between Casting?

Tags: android, between, dbflow

There are 1~20 numbers in List. And i want to take 1~10 numbers. but below code can't take 1~10 numbers. only 1 and 10..

how do i do?

```
startNum = 1;
endNum = 10;

public List<Object> findbyBetweenStartEnd(String startNum, String endNum)
{
  return SQLite.select()
        .from(Object.class)
        .where(Object_Table.no.between(startNum).and(endNum))
        .queryList(); 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I Modified your query it is working for me, now getting number's list with start to end value

```
return SQLite.select()
        .from(Object.class)        
        .where(Condition.column(Object_Table.no).between(startNum).and(endNum))
        .queryList();
```